# Has many trough with date verification in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I need to refactor my data relationship since date featured included. I have three models:

```
\App\Product;
discounts()->hasManyThrough('App\Discount', 'App\DiscountProduct', 'product_id','id','id','discount_id');
\App\DiscountProduct;
discount()->belongsTo('App\Discount', 'discount_id');
\App\Discount;
discountProduct()->hasMany('App\DiscountProduct');
```

---

1. discounts_product table: id, discount_id, product_id
2. discounts table: id, name, start_date, end_date, etc.
3. products table: id, name, price, etc.

---

When I call `$product->with('discounts')`
the result is something like this

```
{"id": 1,
 "name": "Wild Blue Shirt",
 "discounts": [{
     "method": "per_product",
     "type": "percentage",
     "nominal": 10,
     "start_date": "2018-03-01 16:34:50", <= this is my problem
     "end_date": "2018-03-31 16:34:50", <= this is my problem
      },...other expired discounts],
},...other products
```

My question is: **How do I filter the current (today) discount for each products?**

I have tried this:

```
\App\DiscountProduct;
currentDiscount() {
   return $this->belongsTo("App\Discount", 'discount_id')->whereRaw('now() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date');
};
```

then

```
$product->with('discounts.currentDiscount'); <= doesn't worked
```

---

This is worked for me:

```
$product_list = $products->with('variants')->with('discounts')->get();
$product_list->transform(function($product) use ($discounts){
   $data = $product;
   $currentDiscount = collect($product->discounts)->map(function($discount){
       $data = null;
       if($discount['end_date'] > now()){
            $data = $discount;
       };
       return $data;
       });
    $data->currentDiscount = $currentDiscount->filter()->first();
    return $data;
});
```

but the problem is i'm unable to use `paginate()` feature, It's so painful to using `forpage()`

otherwise this raw DB is worked also:

```
$products = DB::table('products')
->selectRaw("products.id, products.name, products.price, COALESCE(active_discount.discount_amount,0) AS discount")
->leftJoin(DB::raw("(discount_products.product_id, CAST(IF(discounts.`type`='percentage', ROUND((discounts.nominal/100)*products.price,0) ,discounts.nominal) AS UNSIGNED) AS discount_amount FROM discount_products JOIN discounts ON discount_products.discount_id=discounts.id JOIN products ON discount_products.product_id=products.id WHERE NOW() BETWEEN discounts.start_date AND discounts.end_date ) active_discount"),'products.id', '=', 'active_discount.product_id'));
```

I don't think all of above methods is the best solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem [with pagination/etc] is because your making Raw DB request instead of using Eloquent.

You could [constrain Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

> ## Constraining Eager Loads
>
> Sometimes you may wish to eager load a relationship, but also specify
>   additional query constraints for the eager loading query. Here's an
>   example:
>
> ```
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');
>
> }])->get();
> ```
>
> In this example, Eloquent will only eager load posts where the post's
>   title column contains the word first. Of course, you may call other
>   query builder methods to further customize the eager loading
>   operation:
>
> ```
> $users = App\User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
>     $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
>
> }])->get();
> ```

So in your case, you could do (haven't test it but this should work):

```
$product->with(['discounts' => function ($query) {

        $query->where(['start_date' , '<', now()] , ['end_date', '>' , now()]);

        }])->paginate(10);
```

You could also set it in the model, directly in the relationship:

```
public function currentDiscount()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Discount', 'discount_id')
            ->where(
                ['start_date', '<', now()],
                ['end_date', '>', now()]
            );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this is worked for me. Simple and fast! but how can I get the product which has current discount? your query is showing all the products.